# API loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am trying to call paginated API through loop. It looks like below. API doc is new and does not tell anything about next,offset or anything. Tried adding {page:page} in param but still returning the first 100 rows. Any help.

```
headers = {'key':'key'}
data = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()

Sample response:
{'results': []
'page': 1,
'results_per_page': 100,
'total_results': 25000}
```

Comment: Direct the question to writer of the api?

Comment: Yeah there is no way for us to know what the API author was thinking.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming.